# How to iterate 2 rows at a time in python and append a column with values in second row in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, for-loop

Data:

```
Date    column1 column2 column3 column4
    2021-08-20  19  30  11  8
    2021-08-21  15  25  11  4
    2021-08-22  5   10  5   0
    2021-08-23  25  36  16  9
    2021-08-24  6   6   6   0
```

I want to iterate 2 rows at a time and create a new column it is like backlog from previous day+today :
In every second row of each iteration I want a value like:
df['new_column'] = (df['column2']-df['column4']) from row 2  + (df['column2']-df['column4']) from row1

I am trying this:

```
from itertools import tee
from itertools import zip_longest as izip
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)

for (idx1, row1), (idx2, row2) in pairwise(df.iterrows()):
    print(idx1,row1,"\n\n",idx2,row2,"\n\n")
    df['Backlog_today'][row2] = (df.loc[row2, ['column2']]  - df.loc[row2, ['column4']])
    df['Backlog_yesterday'][row1] = (df.loc[row1, ['column2']]  - df.loc[row1, ['column4']])
    df['new_column'] = df['Backlog_today'] + df['Backlog_yesterday']
```

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subtract values and then add shifted Series by [`Series.add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.add.html) and [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
s = (df['column2']-df['column4'])
df['new_column'] = s.add(s.shift(), fill_value=0)
print (df)
         Date  column1  column2  column3  column4  new_column
0  2021-08-20       19       30       11        8        22.0
1  2021-08-21       15       25       11        4        43.0
2  2021-08-22        5       10        5        0        31.0
3  2021-08-23       25       36       16        9        37.0
4  2021-08-24        6        6        6        0        33.0
```

If need first value `0`:

```
s = (df['column2']-df['column4'])
df['new_column'] = s.add(s.shift()).fillna(0)
print (df)
         Date  column1  column2  column3  column4  new_column
0  2021-08-20       19       30       11        8         0.0
1  2021-08-21       15       25       11        4        43.0
2  2021-08-22        5       10        5        0        31.0
3  2021-08-23       25       36       16        9        37.0
4  2021-08-24        6        6        6        0        33.0
```

**Performance** in sample data:

```
#5k rows
df = pd.concat([df] * 1000, ignore_index=True)


In [141]: %%timeit 
     ...: df.rolling(2)[['column2', 'column4']].sum().agg(lambda x:x[0] - x[1] ,axis=1).fillna(0)
     ...: 
46.8 ms ± 274 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [142]: %%timeit
     ...: s = (df['column2']-df['column4'])
     ...: s.add(s.shift(), fill_value=0)
     ...: 
     ...: 
460 µs ± 4.16 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [143]: %%timeit
     ...: s = (df['column2']-df['column4'])
     ...: s.add(s.shift()).fillna(0)
     ...: 
     ...: 
496 µs ± 8.35 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thank You for your response!! Let me check this

Comment: No, I didn't need first value 0, you first answer works perfectly in this situation. Thank You for this!!

Comment: I was just wondering, what do you use, if you want all the rows above and not just 2 rows using shift()? .shift(len(df)) wont give you right answer. It will still be the same?

Answer (score 2):

Use `rolling` to compute the sum between today and yesterday then `aggregate` by subtracting the two columns.

```
df['new_column'] = df.rolling(2, min_periods=1)[['column2', 'column4']].sum() \
                     .agg(lambda x:x[0] - x[1] ,axis=1).fillna(0)
print(df)

# Output:
         Date  column1  column2  column3  column4  new_column
0  2021-08-20       19       30       11        8        22.0
1  2021-08-21       15       25       11        4        43.0
2  2021-08-22        5       10        5        0        31.0
3  2021-08-23       25       36       16        9        37.0
4  2021-08-24        6        6        6        0        33.0
```

Comment: Thank You for your response!! Let me check this

Comment: Hey this works too! Its just that in the first row, I needed it to be 22, because there is no previous date.

Comment: I updated my answer according to your comment.